# How to initialize Firebase App in Cloud Functions with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following imports:

```
const {
  getDatabase,
} = require("firebase-admin/database");

getDatabase().ref("message").set("Hi!");
```

But when I deploy the function, I get:

> The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

What exactly should I initialize? Isn't the import enough?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize firebase config in your app:

OBS: you can get your `service.json` file going to: firebase console -> project settings (little cog in top left screen side) -> service account then click on 'generate a new private key' button.

```
// config file
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
// you can have multiple services file for dev and prod environments
import * as prodServiceAccount from 'path/to/service.json'
import * as devServiceAccount from 'path/to/service.dev.json'
const serviceAccount = process.env.AMBIENT === 'development' ?
  devServiceAccount : prodServiceAccount

const params = {
  type: serviceAccount.type,
  projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
  privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
  privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
  clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
  clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
  authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
  tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
  authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
  clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url
}

admin.initializeApp( {
  credential: admin.credential.cert( params )
} )

export const database = getDatabase()
```

And use it like this:

```
// import your database and use it
import {database} from 'path/to/config'

....

database.ref("message").set("Hi!")
```

Now you can call any Firebase services/functions.

You can also find more about this process [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=pt#add-sdk).